# Calculus of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}( \frac{1}{2^n})$, $n$ is even

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}( \frac{1}{2^n}) = \frac{1}{3}$, where $n$ can only be an even integer.

That is, how can I use linear algebra to prove that $\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^4} + \frac{1}{2^6} + \frac{1}{2^8} + \cdots = \frac{1}{3}$?

I heard some people saying that linear algebra help them to solve the aforementioned problem. Can anyone explain to me in detail how to get the solution $\frac{1}{3}$?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: The series you have written is ${1\over2}++{1\over2^2}+{1\over3^3}=\cdots$  not $\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^4} + \frac{1}{2^6} + \frac{1}{2^8} + \cdots$ Linear algebra has nothing to do with the problem. This is a geometric series, and you use calculus to sum it.

Comment: "I heard some people saying linear algebra ... " Which people, some of your family members?

Comment: Yes I may be wrong, I think linear algebra is not involved here to do the calculation.

Comment: @Christina Nice that your problem is clarified. I prefer asking some details before posting an answer. Btw, I´m sure that your family members are great.

Comment: @callculus Yes! I believe they are great:d cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that the set of all even (non-zero) integers is $2\mathbb N^*$. This gives the following sum to compute
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^{2k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{4^k}=\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{1}{1-1/4}=\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{4}{3}=\dfrac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: What has you answer to do with linear algebra?

Comment: Nothing, but I still explain in details how to get $1/3$ which was the question. If somebody has an answer using linear algebra I would be glad to read it but I think that the easiest way to get to the solution does not involve linear algebra

Comment: Except that the last question is actually " Can anyone explain to me in detail how to get the solution 1/3". OP just mentions that some people talked about linear algebra but OP seems to want an answer using or not linear algebra

Comment: Yes exactly, your answer is sufficient for me. But how you got $\frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{1-1/4}$? Can you add more details in your answer please?

Comment: @Christina that is a geometric series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Ah ok great! thank you!

Comment: @Christina:  sum of infinite geometric series is $\dfrac a {1-r}$, where first term is $a$ and ratio of successive terms is $r$

Comment: Yes I see. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

IF the sum is finite (call it $S$) , it satisfies the equation  $4S=1+S$ which implies $(4-1)S=1$ and so $S=1/3$.   You might call this "linear algebra", but it's a stretch.  This does not prove the series converges, that is, actually represents a number.